# Google Sheets - If column contains specific value results in "A", if not "B"

Tags: google-sheets

[ANSWERED]
If a cell in column F contains "0" I want column H to show "COMPLETE". If the cell in column F contains anything else I want column H to show "INCOMPLETE".
(This might be something simple, I'm very new to Google Sheets. I looked around and tried a couple things but just ended up more confused.)

Update: Using this formula: ={"Completition status";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(F2:F89="","",IF(F2:F89=0,"COMPLETE","INCOMPLETE")))}

Substitute "F2:F89" with the range of cells you want it to be (if it's too big a range it will give you an error)

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IF statement for this. In your case, you can use this code in your H column

```
IF(A1 = 0,"Complete","Incomplete")
```

Then match the row number to the current row. For example, in row 10 you would write:

```
IF(A10 = 0,"Complete","Incomplete")
```

The If function is documented here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use just a single formula without need to copy a formula to each new row that is added, use the following formula in the top row, cell H1:

```
={"Completition status";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(F1:F="";"";IF(F1:F=0;"COMPLETE";"INCOMPLETE")))}
```

Comment: Thank you! At first this was giving me a "Result was not expanded automatically, please insert more rows." I added a range limit and it started working (also changed the starting cell to F2, the title row was making it one row down from where it should be.) It's working now but it's adding another "COMPLETE" at the bottom for some reason (there is no number in that row). I tried adding a random number and it just shifts it down one row. Any Idea? Here's the edited formula: ={"Completition status";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(F1:F89="","",IF(F2:F=0,"COMPLETE","INCOMPLETE")))}

Comment: use ={"Completition status";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(F1:F89="","",IF(F1:F89=0,"COMPLETE","INCOMPLETE")))}  The ranges F1:F89 must match

Comment: Thank you so much for helping! It's working perfectly now.